# How to use json format into jinja2 template

Tags: python, json, templates, jinja2

I have taken json format from .xlsx , now I want to use that json into jinja2 template, but I am not getting how I can use it to get desired output.

this is my json:

```
{'Nodeb_IN_New': [{'policy_id': 107, 'default': 'class-default', 'class': 'mobility-platinum', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': ['ef']}, {'policy_id': 107, 'default': '', 'class': 'mobility-gold-new', 'mpls': 'h2', 'qos': 5, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': ['af41']}, {'policy_id': 107, 'default': '', 'class': 'mobility-silver-new', 'mpls': 'l1', 'qos': 4, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']}, 'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN':[{'policy_id': 102, 'default': '', 'class': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'mpls': 'h1', 'qos': 7, 'nokia': 'dscp-fc-map', 'dscp': ['ef', 'nc1']}]}
```

my code to generate json:

```
import json

# Jinja Part
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

# Port config Class
qos_template = env.get_template('jinjaQosTemplate3.txt')

def myfun(list):
    res=dict()
    qos=None
    d={}
    li=[]
    for row in list:
        if row[0]=="":
            res[qos]=dict()
            res[qos]['policy_id']=row[1]
            res[qos]['default']=row[2]
            res[qos]['class']=row[3]
            res[qos]['mpls']=row[4]
            res[qos]['qos']=row[5]
            res[qos]['nokia']=row[6]
            res[qos]['dscp']=row[7]
        else:
            qos=row[0]
            res[qos]=dict()
            res[qos]['policy_id']=row[1]
            res[qos]['default']=row[2]
            res[qos]['class']=row[3]
            res[qos]['mpls']=row[4]
            res[qos]['qos']=row[5]
            res[qos]['nokia']=row[6]
            res[qos]['dscp']=row[7]
        x = res.keys()
        keylist = []
        keylist.extend(iter(x))
        if keylist[0] in d.keys():
               d[keylist[0]].append(res[qos])
        else:
               d[keylist[0]] = []
               d[keylist[0]].append(res[qos])
    print(d)
    print(json.dumps(d))

    output = qos_template.render(data=d,zip=zip)
    file1.writelines(output)
    file1.writelines('\n')
```

I want to use json to get desired output which is like this:

```
/configure qos
        dscp-fc-map 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            dscp ef fc "h1"
            dscp nc1 fc "h1"
        exit


        ingress-cos-policy 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            dscp-fc-map 100
        exit

        sap-ingress 100 create
            description "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN"
            ingress-cos-policy 100
            policer 7 create 
            exit
            fc "h1" create
                policer 7
            exit
        exit

-----------------
/configure qos
        dscp-fc-map 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            dscp ef fc "h1"
            dscp af11 fc "l1"
            dscp af21 fc "l1"
            dscp af31 fc "l1"
            dscp af41 fc "h2"
            default-fc be   
        exit

        ingress-cos-policy 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            dscp-fc-map 101
        exit


        sap-ingress 101 create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            ingress-cos-policy 101
            policer 1 create
            exit
            policer 4 create
            exit
            policer 5 create
            exit
            policer 7 create
            exit
            fc "be" create
                policer 1
            exit
            fc "h1" create
                policer 7
            exit
            fc "h2" create
                policer 5
            exit
            fc "l1" create
                policer 4
            exit
        exit
```

I tried to make this jinja template but I think its wrong so please suggest how can I make template to get output like desired.

```
/configure qos 
{%-for k,v in data.items()%}
    {%-if (v['nokia'])|length>0%}
    {{v['nokia']}} {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            {%-for i in range(0,(v['dscp'])|length)%}
            dscp {{v['dscp'][i]}} fc "{{v['mpls']}}"
            {%endfor%}
        exit
    {%endif%}
        ingress-cos-policy {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking
            {{v['nokia']}} {{v['policy_id']}}
        exit

        sap-ingress {{v['policy_id']}} create
            description "{{k}}"
            ingress-cos-policy {{v['policy_id']}}
    {%-for j in queue%}
            policer {{queue}} create
            exit
    {%-endfor%}
    {%-for j,l in zip(queue,v['dscp'])%}
            fc "{{v['dscp']}}" create
                policer {{queue}}
            exit
    {%-endfor%}
        exit           
{%-endfor%}
```

And the output I am getting is like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
echo "QOS Configuration"
----------------------------------------------

        ingress-cos-policy  create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            enable-dscp-exp-remarking

        exit

        sap-ingress  create
            description "Nodeb_IN_New"
            ingress-cos-policy 
        exit
```

Comment: What is  the role of `myfun` and the `list` argument?  Share more of the your code  and explain what is wrong.

Comment: first I have stored excel data into list than converted it into json. nothing is wrong with the code. its just for reference. now I want to make a template that can take the json and give me desired output with the help of template. so need help in template that can provide desired output.

Comment: Do you have code that calls Jinja with your data structure and a jinja template? If you have it - share it. If you dont have such code, find a jina tutorial like https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/jinja2-templating-engine-tutorial-4bd31fb4aea3 and learn jinja

Comment: yes I have. which call jinja template:  # Jinja Part
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

# Port config Class
qos_template = env.get_template('jinjaQosTemplate3.txt')

Comment: Edit the post and add the code there. Make the following clear to the reader: 1) What is the jinja template 2) What is the data structure that you are using 3) What is wrong with your current output.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: OK . The reasons that you get this output are 1) `{%-if (v['nokia'])|length>0%}` is never true so the the first block of code is never generated. Rest of the blocks are not generated since it is not clear what is `queue`.  Fix the data structure you have posted (it is not a valid python dict) and we will be able to continue from there.